# How to use an interface with methods that has in input or return type the reference of the interface?

Tags: java

I have an interface like that:

```
public interface IntTree {
    public int getValue();
    public int childrenNumber(); 
    public int nodes (); 
    public int height (); 
    public boolean equals (IntTree t); 
    public void addChild (IntTree child); 
    public IntTree followPath(int[] path);
    public void visit ();
    public void printIntTree ();
}
```

And I don't know how to implement `MyTree` because there are a lot of references on the interface: for example:

```
public void addChild (IntTree child);
public IntTree followPath(int[] path);
public boolean equals (IntTree t);
```

So I don't understand how to use `IntTree` reference. I did all my methods with a cast for example:

```
public class MyTree implements IntTree {
    private int data;
    private LinkedList<MyTree> children; //I have to declare it IntTree or MyTree?

    public MyTree(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new LinkedList<>();
    }
    public void addChild(IntTree child){
        this.children.addFirst((MyTree) child);
    }
    public LinkedList<MyTree> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
}
```

But my teacher said that is wrong to do that, how can I get access for example to my children list etc if I can't cast it to `MyTree` object? how can I do a method `public IntTree followPath(int[] path);` if `MyTree object = this` and it's `!=` from `IntTree`? Please explain me, I am getting mad:

And for the other methods that have nothing in input and not return a reference of the Interface I can implement it with the constructor of `MyTree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> private LinkedList children; //I have to declare it IntTree or MyTree?

You should use `IntTree` here as then you'll add elements that implements IntTree interface so it could be a different class object then `MyTree`. What you're doing is not type safe, take this as example:

```
public class SomeTree implements IntTree {
    //some code
}
```

And then lets use `SomeTree` with our `MyTree`.

```
MyTree myTree = new MyTree();
SomeTree child = new SomeTree();

myTree.addChild(child); //Here we get ClassCastException
```

If you need to implement `IntTree` interface without changing it then you should leave it as it is without casting. Your code should always be type safe if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to modify the interface declaration then you can change it as following:

```
public interface IntTree<T extends IntTree<T>> {
    public int getValue();
    public int childrenNumber();
    public int nodes ();
    public int height ();
    public boolean equals (T t);
    public void addChild (T child);
    public T followPath(int[] path);
    public void visit ();
    public void printIntTree ();
}
```

Then you should declare your class as:

```
public class MyTree implements IntTree<MyTree>
```

Now your methods will look like:

```
public void addChild (MyTree child);
public MyTree followPath(int[] path);
public boolean equals (MyTree t);
```

So you'll be able to work with them in the way you want.

Comment: I can't modify the interface!

Comment: Then casting is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

The equals method is unnecesary, it's already defined in Object. You should override it.

For addChildren, you could store a IntTree list:

```
public class MyTree implements IntTree {
    private int data;
    private LinkedList<IntTree> children; //I have to declare it IntTree or MyTree?

    public MyTree(int data) {
       this.data = data;
       this.children = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void addChild(IntTree child) {
        children.addFirst(child);
    }

    public LinkedList<IntTree> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public IntTree followPath(int[] path) throws NoSuchTreeException {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            path[i] = path[i] - 1;
        }

        IntTree oggetto = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            int index = path[i];
            if (index >= oggetto.getChildren().size() || oggetto.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                throw new NoSuchTreeException();
            }
            oggetto = oggetto.getChildren().get(i);
        }

        return oggetto;
    }
```

In "followpath" i changed the type of oggeto asswell.

The key is hold the most general reference while avoiding the casts.

Comment: This will not work because IntTree does not provide getChildren() method.

Comment: @PavloViazovskyy that's true, he should add it to the interface asswell

Comment: @amchacon the problem is that IntTree oggetto = this; it can't see the getChildren() method because it's not defined in the interface. I can't change my interface as I want :) I did all methods but using casts and my teacher said that is wrong to do that.

Comment: @HKing add it to the interface :)

Answer (score 0):

When you define an inteface it means that you are defining all methods that you will use in the class implementation.

In your interface you have the following methods:

```
public interface IntTree {
    public int getValue();
    public int childrenNumber();
    public int nodes ();
    public int height ();
    public boolean equals (IntTree t);
    public void addChild (IntTree child);
    public IntTree followPath(int[] path) throws NoSuchTreeException;
    public void visit ();
    public void printIntTree ();
}
```

These methods must be overwritten in `MyTree` class, for example:

```
public class MyTree implements IntTree {
    private int data;
    private LinkedList<MyTree> children; //I have to declare it IntTree or MyTree?

    public MyTree(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.children = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public IntTree followPath(int[] path) throws NoSuchTreeException {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            path[i] = path[i] - 1;
        }

        MyTree oggetto = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            int index = path[i];
            if (index >= oggetto.getChildren().size() || oggetto.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                throw new NoSuchTreeException();
            }
            oggetto = oggetto.getChildren().get(i);
        }

        return oggetto;
    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 0; //Implement the logic for this method
    }

    @Override
    public int childrenNumber() {
        return 0; //Implement the logic for this method
    }

    @Override
    public int nodes() {
        return 0; //Implement the logic for this method
    }

    @Override
    public int height() {
        return 0; //Implement the logic for this method
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(IntTree t) {
        return false; //Implement the logic for this method
    }

    public void addChild(IntTree child) {
        this.children.addFirst((MyTree) child);
    }

    public LinkedList<MyTree> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }

    @Override
    public void visit() {
        //Implement the logic for this method
    }

    @Override
    public void printIntTree() {
        //Implement the logic for this method
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know it but the problem is another,I did all methods but I use the cast method like: (MyTree) child. That's the problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I wrote that remark because I didn't see overwritten those methods in the implementation.